# View to get the minimum date with a complicated condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, minimum

I have a table in SQL Server like this:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| DateFrom | Completed | EmployeeID |
+----------+-----------+------------+
DateFrom: date not null -- unique for each EmployeeID
Completed: bit not null
EmployeeID: bigint not null
```

- Each row belongs to a subperiod defined by a start date and can be completed or not.
- Each employee can have multiple subperiods.
- A period is defined by a list of ordered subperiods until the last subperiod is completed.

I want to create a view that will return the start date of the last period for every EmployeeID like this:

1. If there is no Completed is true, get the minimum DateFrom. [The employee has one period which is still not completed]

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| DateFrom | Completed | EmployeeID |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|2021-01-01|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-05|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-09|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-10|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-07|   false   |     2      |
|2021-01-15|   false   |     2      |
+----------+-----------+------------+

Expected Result:
2021-01-01 for EmployeeID = 1
2021-01-07 for EmployeeID = 2
```

2. Else, return the minimum DateFrom after the last Completed is true. [The last period is still not completed]

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| DateFrom | Completed | EmployeeID |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|2021-01-01|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-05|   true    |     1      |
|2021-01-09|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-10|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-07|   true    |     2      |
|2021-01-15|   false   |     2      |
+----------+-----------+------------+

Expected Result:
2021-01-09 for EmployeeID = 1
2021-01-15 for EmployeeID = 2
```

3. If the maximum DateFrom has Completed=true, return the minimum DateFrom before the last Completed is true and after the true before it, if exists. [The last period is completed with multiple subperiods]

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| DateFrom | Completed | EmployeeID |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|2021-01-01|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-05|   true    |     1      |
|2021-01-09|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-10|   true    |     1      |
|2021-01-07|   false   |     2      |
|2021-01-15|   true    |     2      |
+----------+-----------+------------+

Expected Result:
2021-01-09 for EmployeeID = 1
2021-01-07 for EmployeeID = 2
```

4. If the maximum DateFrom has Completed=true and there is no other rows or the row before it has Completed=true, return the maximum DateFrom. [The last period is completed with one subperiod]

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| DateFrom | Completed | EmployeeID |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|2021-01-01|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-05|   false   |     1      |
|2021-01-09|   true    |     1      |
|2021-01-10|   true    |     1      |
|2021-01-07|   true    |     2      |
+----------+-----------+------------+

Expected Result:
2021-01-10 for EmployeeID = 1
2021-01-07 for EmployeeID = 2
```

I am looking for the most optimized solution.

I tried this, but I get a NULL value in the third example:

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT EmployeeID
        , MAX(CASE WHEN Completed = 0 THEN NULL ELSE DateFrom END) MaxDateFrom 
    FROM TableDates
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
)
SELECT TableDates.EmployeeID, MIN(TableDates.DateFrom) DateFrom
FROM T
LEFT JOIN TableDates ON T.EmployeeID = TableDates.EmployeeID
    AND (T.MaxDateFrom IS NULL OR TableDates.DateFrom > T.MaxDateFrom)
GROUP BY TableDates.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation -- with a bunch of logic.  Assuming that you have rows for every day, I think this does what you want:

```
select employeeid,
       (case when -- case 4
                  min(completed) = max(completed) and
                  min(completed) = 'true'
             then max(datefrom) 
             when -- case 1
                  min(completed) = max(completed) and
                  min(completed) = 'false'
             then min(datefrom) 
             when -- case 3
                  max(datefrom) = max(case when completed = 'true' then datefrom end)
             then min(case when completed_seqnum = 1 then datefrom end)
             else dateadd(day, 1, max(case when completed = 'true' then datefrom end))
        end)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when completed = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by employeeid order by datefrom desc) as completed_seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by employeeid;
```

The need for a row every day is really just a convenience -- allowing the code to add one day to get the date after a particular "true" false, for instance.  This could also be accomplished using `lead()` in the subquery.

Note:  This does not handle all conditions (at least with a non-NULL date.  For instance, it returns `NULL` when there is a sequence of "true"s at the end of the data.

If this is an issue -- this version of your question has been asked.  Ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  I also think that you might be able to explain the *problem* you are trying to solve and simplify the explanation.

EDIT:

If dates are missing, you can use:

```
select employeeid,
       (case when -- case 4
                  min(completed) = max(completed) and
                  min(completed) = 'true'
             then max(datefrom) 
             when -- case 1
                  min(completed) = max(completed) and
                  min(completed) = 'false'
             then min(datefrom) 
             when -- case 3
                  max(datefrom) = max(case when completed = 'true' then datefrom end)
             then min(case when completed_seqnum = 1 then datefrom end)
             else max(case when completed = 'true' then next_datefrom end)
        end)
from (select t.*,
             lead(datefrom) over (partition by employeeid order by datefrom) as next_datefrom,
             sum(case when completed = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by employeeid order by datefrom desc) as completed_seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by employeeid;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just, please note that we do not have rows for everyday.

Comment: @FaresDellel . . . Just use `lead()` in the subquery and use the next date instead of `dateadd()`.  Your sample data does have data on every day.

Comment: We can optimize the solution like this:
`select EmployeeID,
       (case when min(completed_seqnum) = 0 then min(case when completed_seqnum = 0 then DateFrom end) 
             else min(case when completed_seqnum = 1 then DateFrom end)
        end) FinalResult
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when completed = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by EmployeeID order by DateFrom desc) as completed_seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by EmployeeID;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working query. Its probably over complicated, but I leave the simplification to you.

It handles the 3 cases, all partitioned by EmployeeId as requested, as follows:

1. When no `Completed=1` exists, detected using the `sum(Completed) over()`, then `first_value(DateFrom)` is used.
2. When the last row value is `completed=1` and the preceding row is `completed=0`, detected using `last_value(Completed)` and `lag(Completed)` then `max(case when Completed = 0 then DateFrom else null end)` is used.
3. The tricky case, when a `Completed=1` exists and its not last. In this case the DateFrom of the most recent row where `Completed=1` is found and then the `min(DateFrom)` is found for all rows more recent than the row previously detected, until the preceding `Completed=1`.
4. If the last row has `completed=1` and the second to last row has `completed=1` then use the `DateFrom` from the last row. Coalesce ensures this if all other options are null.

```
insert into @Test (EmployeeId, DateFrom, Completed)
values
-- Scenario 1
(1, '2021-01-01', 0),
(1, '2021-01-02', 0),
(1, '2021-01-03', 0),
-- Scenario 2
(2, '2021-01-01', 0),
(2, '2021-01-02', 1),
(2, '2021-01-03', 0),
(2, '2021-01-04', 0),
-- Scenario 3
(3, '2021-01-01', 0),
(3, '2021-01-02', 1),
(3, '2021-01-03', 0),
(3, '2021-01-04', 1),
-- Special case, single row
(4, '2021-01-01', 1),
-- Scenario 4
(5, '2021-01-01', 0),
(5, '2021-01-02', 0),
(5, '2021-01-03', 1);

with cte as (
  select *
    -- First value of DateFrom over all rows (not the default)
    , first_value (DateFrom) over (partition by EmployeeId order by DateFrom asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) FirstDateFrom
    -- Last value of Completed over all rows (not the default)
    , last_value (Completed) over (partition by EmployeeId order by DateFrom asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) LastCompleted
    -- Find the Date of the last row with Completed = 1
    , max (case when Completed = 1 then DateFrom else null end) over (partition by EmployeeId order by DateFrom asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) LastCompletedNew
    -- Regular row number
    , row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId order by DateFrom desc) RowNumber
    -- Total number of rows with Completed = 1
    , sum(convert(int,Completed)) over (partition by EmployeeId) SumOfCompleted
    -- Max value of DateFrom where Completed = 0
    , max(case when Completed = 0 then DateFrom else null end) over (partition by EmployeeId order by DateFrom asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) MaxDateFrom
    -- Check the lagged complete to see if the last 2 rows are completed = 1
    , lag(Completed) over (partition by EmployeeId order by DateFrom asc) LaggedComplete
    -- Borrowed from Gordon to check which rows are prior to the last Completed = 1 and before the preceding Completed = 1
    , sum(case when completed = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by employeeid order by datefrom desc) as completed_seqnum
  from @Test
)
select
  EmployeeId
  -- Use the only DateFrom if there is only one
  , coalesce(case
    -- Scenario 1
    when SumOfCompleted = 0 then FirstDateFrom
    when LastCompleted = 1 then
      case
      -- Scenario 4
      when coalesce(LaggedComplete,0) = 1 then DateFrom
      -- Scenario 3
      else Scenario3
      end
    -- Scenario 2
    else ActualResult
    end, DateFrom) FinalResult
  --, * -- Uncomment for working
from (
  select *
    -- Find the lowest DateFrom which is greater then the DateFrom of the last row where Completed = 1
    , min(case when DateFrom > LastCompletedNew then DateFrom else null end) over (partition by EmployeeId) ActualResult
    -- Find the min DateFrom over the rows between the last Completed=1 and the Completed=1 before it (if it exists)
    , min(case when completed_seqnum = 1 then DateFrom else null end) over (partition by EmployeeId order by DateFrom asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) Scenario3
  from cte
) x
-- Because we have calculated the same result for every row we just take the first
where RowNumber = 1
order by x.EmployeeId asc, x.DateFrom asc;
```

Note: This assumes that there is only a single row per date.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just, I want to make the GROUP BY, if you can help.

Comment: @FaresDellel I am guessing your forgot to put an EmployeeId in your sample data? See edits.

Comment: I mentionned that I will make a GROUP BY in the first post, then I edited it with a complete example.

Comment: @FaresDellel but your sample data doesn't include it - it should.

Comment: @FaresDellel your sample data should include such conditions.

Comment: Sorry to mention that if we have one row with Complete is true or when the last and before the last have true, it should return the DateFrom of the last row.

Comment: @FaresDellel try now, and please update your question to have complete requirements.

Comment: @FaresDellel sorry I have to go to bed. I recommend you understand how this query works and then adapt it to your new requirement. I would still recommend you updating your sample data with an EmployeeId to that its representation. For the future please ensure you have your requirements correct before posting.

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated the requirements. I appreciate your help and I will consider your notes in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help.